# What does EEMEM stand for?

Tags: definition, eeprom

I'm looking for the definition of EEMEM... I'm guessing it's electronically erasable memory, but not sure. Is this different than EEPROM?

The reason behind this -- I'm looking at an entry of a digital potentiometer that has the acronym next to it, and I'm looking to fit it into a matrix of memory types that I have, so I need to know if it is EEPROM or something different.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=eemem+digital+potentiometer - comes up in this specific AD52* context. D:

Comment: However, it doesn't appear to be the same as EEPROM - no clear cycle. More like NVRAM?

Comment: the articles say that eemem is interchangable with non volatile mem but never actually define the acronym (poor technical writing if you ask me) so i guess my question still sits, what does it mean, what is it?

Comment: So I found the specs for the digital pot, for whatever reason the first time i searched for them i couldnt find it, and it lists the memory type as EEPROM, which answers the real questions i had. heres the [link](https://www.tme.eu/en/details/ad5259brmz10/digital-potentiometers/analog-devices/?brutto=1&gclid=Cj0KCQiA8f_eBRDcARIsAEKwRGcE5amfcozSXRnwi7GfhrSH_wxE2QB5aRGEFAZPA51DPjPDzCYkqusaAmWSEALw_wcB)

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question.

Although I couldn't find an exact acronym definition for EEMEM, the word is interchangeable with Non-volatile memory.

For the exact pot that I was looking at, the memory type is EEPROM as found in the specifications [here](https://www.tme.eu/en/details/ad5259brmz10/digital-potentiometers/analog-devices/?brutto=1&gclid=Cj0KCQiA8f_eBRDcARIsAEKwRGcE5amfcozSXRnwi7GfhrSH_wxE2QB5aRGEFAZPA51DPjPDzCYkqusaAmWSEALw_wcB)